# Why use attrs in Beautiful Soup for scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
for link in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'title"'}):
        for links in link.find_all('a'):
```

If I use `attrs`, then links are scraped, but if I use `tag`, then they are not scraped. So what's the difference between `attrs` and `tag`?

Comment: Just answered the main point. To help you with the specific behavior, why things are scraped or not, please improve your question  - How to create [mcve] (add url/html and expectetd result) - Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Main difference between `tag` and `attribute / attrs` is that a `tag` represents an `element`, while an `attribute` describs the characteristics of an `element`.